# Is NSSizeFromCGSize nothing more than a cast operation?

Tags: cocoa

The source is as follows:

```
NS_INLINE NSSize NSSizeFromCGSize(CGSize cgsize) {
    union _ {NSSize ns; CGSize cg;};
    return ((union _ *)&cgsize)->ns;
}
```

To me this just looks like an overcomplicated cast (reading a chunk of memory differently than originally intended).  Is there a reason that this syntax is needed?  I only ask because I've never seen this before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is effectively a cast. In C, and hence Objective-C, you cannot cast one structure type to another - which in general is a good thing! However you can cast a pointer to anything to a pointer to anything else - which in general is dangerous...

So if, and only if, you really know two structures are identical you can cast the value from a variable of one structure type to a value of the other structure type by taking the address of the variable (`&cgsize`), casting the resultant pointer (`(union _ *)`), and then dereferencing the pointer (`->ns`) to get the type cast value. Any decent compiler will optimize this away and do a straight copy of the value.

Comment: hmm, interesting, I was not presented with any errors when attempting to simply cast, but maybe that is because they are identically typedefed under 64bit.  Thanks for the info!

Comment: @borrrden - you are right, you can "cast" something to itself - it is a nop - and under 64-bit the NS and CG geometry types are just aliases of each other so the "cast" works. There is an (undocumented) define `NSGEOMETRY_TYPES_SAME_AS_CGGEOMETRY_TYPES` which appears to allow testing of whether the types are the same - it is currently either defined with the value `1` or undefined (rather than defined with the value `0`), you can test for exactly this using `#if defined(NSGEOMETRY_TYPES_SAME_AS_CGGEOMETRY_TYPES) && (NSGEOMETRY_TYPES_SAME_AS_CGGEOMETRY_TYPES == 1)`.